# perl script for rookies

Tags: perl, arguments

I have to use UNIX to be able to enter a Perl script that takes up to 6, and no greater than 6 arguments and be able to display the multiplication of the arguments and the factorial of the arguments.

i.e.

```
perl -w MultFac.pl 3 3 4 5
```

The arguments are `3 3 4 5`

Number of arguements is `4`

Multiplication = `180`

Factorial = `24`

I've never used Perl and kind of just jumped in without knowing anything about it at all, if this was C i'd be able to do this task with relative ease. Knowing how to do this seems like it'd be a good use for beginners such as myself to be able to use print and scan functions as well as using the arguments as variables.

Any and all help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: `@ARGV` contains the arguments passed to Perl, the rest should be relatively easy.

Answer (score 3):

Convert the following oneliner to an script:

```
perl -MList::Util=product -E 'say product(@ARGV),",",product(1..@ARGV)' -- 3 3 4 5
```

prints

```
180,24
```